# Removing rotten cedar siding shingles

Tags: removal, siding, replacement, shingles, cedar

I'm removing some rotten cedar shingles from the side of our house and they are nailed on so tight one over the other that I can't get my [Dasco Pro shingle ripper](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Dasco-Pro-24-in-Shingle-Ripper-640/202519559) behind the shingle to hook the nails and pull them out. I don't want to put too much pressure on the shingle I'm trying to remove because I don't want to crack the shingle above it.

Perhaps I could use a long, thin blade that I can shove up under the shingle that I'm taking out so I can cut the nails that are nailed through it.

Any suggestions as to the best way to cut the nails holding the shingles on and pull the shingles out?

There is an interesting video [here](https://www.finehomebuilding.com/2013/10/28/repairing-damaged-siding-series-whole-shingle-repair).

Comment: I haven’t used one of those pro shingle rippers or even ever seen one on a job, we use a wonder bar a flat crow bar and Or a cat paw for siding shingles or lath.

Comment: Yup, that looks like a rather crude/thick tool aimed at asphalt shingles and roofing nails with some marketing fertilizer about "variety of shingle materials" thrown in. For Cedar siding singles and nails you'll want a tool with a lot more finesse (slim but strong.)

Answer (score 0):

You can literally split the shingles along their grain edge, taking them out in splinters.  Eventually you'll split the shingle right where a nail is, and be able to get both parts.

The tip of your tool appears too crude for your proposed use, which seems to involve saving the row of shingles above.  Keep in mind you'll be unable to nail new shingles in those places.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using a chisel and hammer  to split the shingles. It's slow but it's working. When I slide the new shingle in place I'll put a nail in at an angle just under the drip edge of the row above and knock the nail the rest of the way with a nail punch.

Comment: The issue I have now is that I need a long, sharp hack saw type blade (maybe a keyhole saw) that I can slide up and use to cut off nails that my shingle ripper can't hook. These nails are creating a "log jam" of pieces of shingle and I can't move the splinters that I've cut with my chisel.